# Server 2008 system tray icons missing

Tags: audio, windows-server-2008, notification-area

Server 2008 64 Bit used as work station on laptop.   Volume network icon missing just went from system tray.

What steps required to redisplay them?

Comment: Please add a windows-server-2008 tag! (or similar)

Comment: Done; I added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix and restore the missing system icons in Vista (similar steps in Server 2008) notification area or system tray, right click on the black/empty space on the system tray itself, or on the taskbar.

In the Taskbar and Start Menu Properties dialog window that appears, click on Notification Area tab if it’s not already there.

[image]

In the System Icons section, tick the check box for Clock, Volume, Network or Power components to display the corresponding icons in system tray.

Comment: What's with the image, scoopdreams? :)

Comment: @alex : whut? whut's with the image? as in it's redundant?? or is there some hidden porn reference I can't see? :)

Comment: my bad - linked image pulled off server. Just realized it when i switched browser. Correcting in 1 minute!

Comment: Much better :). Nice answer, btw!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The Volume and network check boxes were also disabled.  I used gpedit.msc to enable them.

Comment: No worries, we are all just trying to help. Thanks for accepting my answer even though it only half-solved your problem. Do you mind editing your question so you can tell others what you did using gpedit.msc to restore the grayed out settings? It'll help others in the future too with similar troubles.